# Why my Lumen api return a cors error in localhost

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, api, lumen

I have an application in Lumen inside a docker container, to which I make requests locally through postman and it works correctly, but when I make the same call from a react application locally, I get a CORS error.

The call from React

```
const loginPayload = {
            email: this.state.input_email,
            password: this.state.input_password,
        }

        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            }
        }
        
        axios.post("http://192.168.1.149:8081/u/login", loginPayload, config)
            .then(response => {
                //get token from response
                const token = response.data.token;

                //set JWT token to local
                localStorage.setItem("token", token);

                //set token to axios common header
                this.setToken(token);

                //redirect user to home page
                window.location.href = '/'
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And my Lumen configuration

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => '86400',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        ];

        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Routes file:

```
$router->group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function () use ($router) {

    $router->post('u/login', 'UserController@authenticate');
});
```

I'm trying to make a call to my api but it returns an error in localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending a **response** header (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) with your **request**:

```js
const config = {
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
}

axios.post("http://192.168.1.149:8081/u/login", loginPayload, config)
```

But your CORS configuration server-side doesn't allow that request header:

```php
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
```

...so the request doesn't pass the check.

Remove the invalid header from your request.

Generally, to diagnose these issues, compare the headers and other information in the request you're sending (via the Network tab in the browser) to your CORS configuration, and look for mismatches.